# Tasks status before starting with concurrency option

Tags: python, mysql, celery

I have a queue with concurrency of `10`, and when I have 11 tasks running at the same time, Celery doesn't sends anything to the result backend for 11th task, therefore it is not possible to fetch the status of that 1 extra task.

I have tested this situation with Redis and MySQL as the result backend.

Am I missing something or is there anyway to setup a custom state for those pending tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK in my case, I was able to use Celery signal `before-task-publish`:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#before-task-publish